# Burkina Faso Transverse Mercator projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapinfo, burkina-faso

I have coordinates in Adindan UTM30N (Clarke 1880) that I want to re-project into Burkina Faso Transverse Mercator (BFTM). I've created custom projections in QGIS and MapInfo for BFTM using some parameters I've found, but the BFTM coordinates I'm getting when transforming with my custom projection don't match some example coordinates that I have, so I'm wondering if my custom projections are incorrect.
Does anyone have any experience of the BFTM projection or could someone please verify the custom projection definitions I've created, given the BFTM parameters below?

Here's the PROJ4 string I've used to create the projection in QGIS:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-1.5 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs +k_0=0.9996
```

Here's the MapInfo projection string I've created:

```
"BFTM_TM_GRS80", 8, 33, 7, -1.5, 0, 0.9996, 600000, 0
```

And here are the BFTM parameters I have:

"The characteristics of the planimetric coordinate system of Burkina Faso are: The ITRF 2008 reference having as ellipsoid the IAG GRS80 (Half Major Axis a = 6 378 137.00 and Flattening 1/f = 298.257222101); BFTM map projection (transverse cylindrical Mercator projection); The Central Meridian 1° 30' west; The coordinates of the center of the projection (X0 = 600,000.00 m, Y0 = 0.00 m); The scale factor: k0 = 0.9996."

These are 2 example coordinates I have:

```
|Point|X_AdindanUTM30|Y_AdindanUTM30|X_BFTM|Y_BFTM|
|-|----|-----|-----|-----|
|A|485800|1100000|421249.7646|1100298.616|
|B|496482|1100000|431941.1098|1100266.086|
```

These are the BFTM coordinates I get for the same 2 points when using my custom projections:

```
|Point|X_AdindanUTM30|Y_AdindanUTM30|X_BFTM_MyProj|Y_BFTM_MyProj|
|-|----|-----|-----|-----|
|A|485800|1100000|421339.8478|1100648.276|
|B|496482|1100000|432025.7282|1100599.916|
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you're missing the transformation from Adindan to WGS 84. The Burkina Faso geographic coordinate reference system (GeoCRS) is based on ITRF2008, so relatively close to WGS 84. The [EPSG registry](https://www.epsg.org) lists these parameters for [Adindan to WGS 84 in Burkina Faso](https://epsg.org/transformation_1101/Adindan-to-WGS-84-2.html):

```
X translation = -118.0
Y translation = -14.0
Z translation = 218.0
```

This transformation isn't very accurate, but hopefully will get you closer.

Try adding +towgs84=-118.0,-14.0,218.0 to your source data's proj definition.

Disclosure: I work for Esri and I'm a member of the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG geodetic registry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this projection string in MapInfo Pro:

"BFTM TM ITRF2008", 8, 999, 0, -118.0, -14.0, 218.0, 7, -1.5, 0, 0.9996, 600000, 0